# Autohotkey: How to add double quote (") to string

Tags: autohotkey

I have a AutoHotkey script with:

```
IfInString, pp_text, %A_Space%
                {
                    pp_text := %pp_text%                                    
                }
```

So in case %pp_text% contains a space I want to add " at the beginning and end

Example:
pp_text = Hello World
should then become
pp_text = "Hello World"

How can I do this?

Comment: For all those who are wondering why I am using so old and deprecated functions. I use / enhanced activaid which is a very very old autohotkey based tool. Migration to the current version of autohotkey would a lot of work.https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=64118

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [escape](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_EscapeChar.htm#Escape_Sequences) a quote by by putting another quote next to it and you [concatenate](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#concat) with the concatenate operator `.`, but actually you can also just omit the operator 99% of the time.

Other things to fix in your script:
Get rid of that super deprecated legacy command and use [`InStr()`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/InStr.htm) instead.
And when you're in an expression, you refer to a variable by just typing its name. Those double `%` you're using are the legacy way of referring to a variable.
So it's correct in the legacy command, but not in the modern [`:=`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetExpression.htm) assignment.
And also you can omit brackets on one-liner if-statements. But that's of course just going to be down personal preference.

Full script:

```
If (InStr(pp_text, A_Space))
    pp_text := """" pp_text """"
```

Four quotes since the the outer two specify that we're typing a string.

Answer (score 1):

> **Variable names in an [expression](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Expressions) are not enclosed in percent signs**.
>
> Consequently, **literal strings must be enclosed in double quotes** to
> distinguish them from variables.
>
> **To include an actual quote-character
> inside a literal string, specify two consecutive quotes** as shown twice
> in this example: "She said, ""An apple a day.""".

```
pp_text := "Hello World"

If InStr(pp_text, " ")
    pp_text := """Hello World"""
MsgBox  % pp_text
```

EDIT:

To use the name of the variable (not its literal text) in the output expression, you need four quotes, as the **user 0x464e** explained.

```
pp_text := "Hello World"

If InStr(pp_text, " ")
    pp_text := """" pp_text """"
MsgBox  % pp_text
```